# Emacs org-mode agenda filter doesn't work. :(

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have exactly this org file:

```
* TODO EAT                                 :home:
** make 
** me
** a
** sandwich
* TODO CODE                                :home:
** make
** me
** code
* TODO SLEEP                                :bed:
** dream with
** dragons
* TODO REPEAT                              :universe:
```

I want to filter it by tags, so I:

1. `M-x + org-agenda`
2. `m`
3. `home`

Then nothing. As if there wasn't any item tagged with home. Although, as you can see, there is.

I'm I doing something wrong? I can not filter by anything, even the "All TODO's" option displays no items at all.

I really want to get into org-mode. Please help me :(

Answer (score 5):

You are seeing that behavior because that org file needs to be in your agenda (`org-agenda-files`) if you do an unrestricted match for the agenda.  You can specify what files (and directories) to include in your agenda by setting it to a list:

```
(setq org-agenda-files
  '("~/path/to/this.org"
    "~/path/to/another/file.org"
    "~/path/to/org-directory/"))
```

Alternatively you can use org-agenda without including files in your agenda by using the dispatcher to restrict the search to the current buffer or subtree (the current file needn't be in `org-agenda-files`).  Type `<` when you see the dispatcher to cycle among 'unrestricted', 'buffer', and 'subtree'.